# How do I populate GNOME Contacts via CardDav and EDS (Evolution Data Server) for use in Thunderbird?

Tags: 13.04, thunderbird, contacts, gnome-contacts

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and it seems comes with Gnome Contacts.  I'm wondering if there's a way to populate the EDS via CardDAV?

Mainly because I see the Thunderbird has an address book tied to this EDS and Thunderbird itself doesn't support CardDAV.  However I'm thinking if I can get my CardDAV server sycned with EDS, that list will be usable in Thunderbird.

Comment: EDS stands for Evolution Data Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import caldav contacts in thunderbird.

[Sync Google contacts with Thunderbird using CardDav](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/12/15/sync-google-contacts-with-thunderbird-using-carddav/).

But I think What you really want is this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution.

---

You can also use evolution's in-built webdav protocol to add a remote cardav contacts.

### Add Carddav contacts in Evolution:

You can use any carddav server.But here for example,we are going to use free online carddav service [fruux.com](https://fruux.com).

### Step1:

Create a free account on fruux. Cliack on addressbook, then click on `Add new Addressbook` & create a new addressbook, call it `Fruux`.

[image: fruux addressbook]

Click on the respective address book. It will show the address book details. Copy the `source url` from there.

### Step2:

Launch Evolution.

Go to Contacts.

Select "New → Address Book".

### Step3:

Select address-book type `webdav`.

[image]

For `"Server → URL"` enter the full URL (of the desired address book),which you have copied in `step1`.

It will be something like this:

```
Fruux:https://dav.fruux.com/addressbooks/a329827487445/b3380-ec73-45f5-a4d5-afb7h4/
```

(your will be different)

Use the following values:

Username: `YUOR FRUUX USER NAME`

Password: `YOUR FRUUX PASSWORD`

Click Apply.

DONE!

---

### Add Carddav contacts in Evolution (using syncevolution):

We are going to sync fruux addressbook with default evolution addressbook `Personal.`
Craete a fruux addressbook as mentioned above & copy the `source url`. Run following commands in terminal-prompt.

**Step1:**

```
syncevolution --configure --template webdav syncURL=https://dav.fruux.com:443/ username=YOUR-FRUUX-USERNAME password=YOUR-Fruux-Password target-config@Fruux
```

**Step2:**

```
syncevolution --configure database=https://dav.fruux.com:443/addressbooks/c32487894645/b3fd4500-kc893-45d5-g4d5-afb8645315/ backend=carddav target-config@fruux addressbook
```

Replace `database=" "` with the `source-url` you have copied in previous step.

**Step3:**

```
syncevolution --configure --template SyncEvolution_Client syncURL=local://@Fruux username= password= Fruux addressbook
```

**Step4:**

```
syncevolution --configure sync=two-way backend=evolution-contacts database=Personal fruux addressbook
```

**Step6 (Run sync for the first time):**

```
Syncevolution --sync=refreh-from-server fruux addressbook
```

It is recommended to use `--sync=slow` or `--sync=refresh-from-server` for first time sync option to avoid duplicity.

`refresh-from-server` **DELETES EVERYTHING** in client & **REPLACES WITH SERVER** (Opposite for caldav/carddav)

**Step7 (run normal two-way sync):**

```
syncevolution fruux addressbook.
```

You can create a launcher with above command to automate the process.

Comment: Thanks!  That looks like it'll work.  However it seems overly complex.  Add a template, add a source, add a database, add a peer...my head is spinning.  Can you (or someone) please layout how to do a CardDAV sync with SyncEvolution to the local EDS?

Comment: The syncevolution-wiki documentation hasn't completed yet. I will try to provide a answer here.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use a CardDAV address book with Thunderbird, there is no need to go through the EDS.
The [Cardbook addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/cardbook/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming) completely replaces Thunderbird's built-in address book and provides support for CardDAV. You add your remote address book using URL, username and password, hit "Sync" (potentially repeatedly) and watch your contacts come in.

*Nota bene:* If you use HTTPS with a server that does not have a valid certificate (in particular a self-signed one) you need to add an exception for that server in Thunderbird's certificate configuration dialogue first. Otherwise, Cardbook will just report failed validation of the login credentials.